# Apache Camel; How to route all message from queue destinations matching a pattern

Tags: routes, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to route all messages that are received to queue destinations that match pattern like "amq:events:*", where * is the wild card.

```
  <camel:route id="event-route" >
      <camel:from uri="amq:events:*" />
      <camel:to uri="file:work/jms/all-events" />
  </camel:route>
```

Messages can be sent to amq:events:dest1 or amq:events:dest2 etc.

Is there a way to do this in camel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use ActiveMQ wildcards: http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html

See this unit test from Camel itself how it can be done: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConsumeWildcardQueuesTest.java

Notice wildcards is a special ActiveMQ functionality. Not all brokers support something like that.